# Layout view keep always over

Tags: android, android-fragments, toolbar

I'm facing some troubles with lollipop & pre-lollipop devices when implementing the toolbar. The shadow is not shown so I've seen that the most common method to get the shadow is to add a view with a gradient.

This is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Where the toolbar_dropshadow is:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:endColor="#88333333"
        android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

This way the shafow is shown well in the most cases, but there are few cases where the shadow is hidden. In 1 fragment, I have a Map (Googlemap) just below the toolbar, so when it is updated, the shadow dissapears. Also, in other fragment I have a imageview just below the toolbar to, when the image is loaded the shadow dissapears.

So, is there a way I can tell the shadow view to be always in the top, even if the fragment is been updated programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use a RelativeLayout so the toolbar is drawn above other views in the hiearchy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```